# How to bulk delete nodes by ID?

Tags: feeds

I have a large csv of nodes that need to be deleted from the database.

I need something like feeds but for deleting. I know this can be accomplished easily via a custom module but I'm just wondering if there's a module or feed extension I can use.

Answer (score 1):

One solution here, that is slightly different from your question, is to use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)/[Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) & contextual filters on a custom View.

VBO contains an operation for bulk deletion. You can create a contextual filter for *Content: Nid* with the **Allow multiple values** option selected. If you've created a page view, that would allow you to navigate to http://example.com/my_node_delete_vbo_view/1+2+3 wherein you can view all the nodes you want to delete, select them all, then apply the Delete item VBO operation.

The only work involves taking your CSV, slicing it down to just the node column, and replacing the character delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

[bulk delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/bulkdelete)
This module will delete any nodes of a certain node-type using the batch api. It is advised to use the Views Batch Operations module (VBO) for a small number of nodes. But if you have to delete 10.000 nodes this module might be a better option.